# Joining Multiple Lines in Python (Text Formatting)

Tags: python, text, format

I am working on pulling logs through an web API and so far when pulling the logs they return in the following format  (3 events below starting with  and ending with .  My question is what would be the best way to loop through each line and concatenate them so that the result event looks like below.

Current output

```
<attack_headlines version="1.0.1">
  <attack_headline>
    <site_id>1</site_id>
    <category>V2luZG93cyBEaXJlY3RvcmllcyBhbmQgRmlsZXM=</category>
    <subcategory>SUlTIEhlbHA=</subcategory>
    <client_ip>172.17.1.126</client_ip>
    <date>1363735940</date>
    <gmt_diff>0</gmt_diff>
    <reference_id>6D13-DE3D-9539-8980</reference_id>
  </attack_headline>
</attack_headlines>
<attack_headlines version="1.0.1">
  <attack_headline>
    <site_id>1</site_id>
    <category>V2luZG93cyBEaXJlY3RvcmllcyBhbmQgRmlsZXM=</category>
    <subcategory>SUlTIEhlbHA=</subcategory>
    <client_ip>172.17.1.136</client_ip>
    <date>1363735971</date>
    <gmt_diff>0</gmt_diff>
    <reference_id>6D13-DE3D-9539-8981</reference_id>
  </attack_headline>
</attack_headlines>
<attack_headlines version="1.0.1">
  <attack_headline>
    <site_id>1</site_id>
    <category>V2luZG93cyBEaXJlY3RvcmllcyBhbmQgRmlsZXM=</category>
    <subcategory>SUlTIEhlbHA=</subcategory>
    <client_ip>172.17.1.156</client_ip>
    <date>1363735975</date>
    <gmt_diff>0</gmt_diff>
    <reference_id>6D13-DE3D-9539-8982</reference_id>
  </attack_headline>
</attack_headlines>
```

Expected output

```
<attack_headlines version="1.0.1"><attack_headline><site_id>1</site_id<category>V2luZG93cyBEaXJlY3RvcmllcyBhbmQgRmlsZXM=</category<subcategory>SUlTIEhlbHA=</subcategory><client_ip>172.17.1.156</client_ip<date>1363735975</date><gmt_diff>0</gmt_diff<reference_id>6D13-DE3D-9539-8982</reference_id></attack_headline</attack_headlines>
```

Thanks in advance!

```
import json
import os
from suds.transport.https import WindowsHttpAuthenticated

class Helpers:
        def set_connection(self,conf):
                        #SUDS BUG FIXER(doctor)
                        protocol=conf['protocol']
                        hostname=conf['hostname']
                        port=conf['port']
                        path=conf['path']
                        file=conf['file']
                        u_name=conf['login']
                        passwrd=conf['password']
                        auth_type = conf['authType']

                        from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor, Import
                        from suds.client import Client

                        url = '{0}://{1}:{2}/{3}/{4}?wsdl'.format(protocol,
                        hostname,port, path, file)

                        imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
                        d = ImportDoctor(imp)
                        if(auth_type == 'ntlm'):
                                ntlm = WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username=u_name, password=passwrd)
                                client = Client(url, transport=ntlm, doctor=d)
                        else:
                                client = Client(url, username=u_name, password=passwrd, doctor=d)
                        return client
        def read_from_file(self, filename):
                try:
                        fo = open(filename, "r")
                        try:
                                result = fo.read()
                        finally:
                                fo.close()
                                return result
                except IOError:
                        print "##Error opening/reading file {0}".format(filename)
                        exit(-1)


        def read_json(self,filename):
                string=self.read_from_file(filename)
                return json.loads(string)


        def get_recent_attacks(self, client):
            import time
            import base64
            from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
            epoch_time_now = int(time.time())
            epochtimeread = open('epoch_last', 'r')
            epoch_time_last_read = epochtimeread.read()
            epochtimeread.close()
            epoch_time_last = int(float(epoch_time_last_read))
            print client.service.get_recent_attacks("",epoch_time_last,epoch_time_now,1,"",15)
```

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: Is this being returned as a single text block with line-breaks or are you reading lines from a file or file object?

Comment: WillOEM I believe single text block... see my code above ... which is getting called by another script.

Comment: Don't use reserved words like "string". Use meaningful and not yet used names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just a single, large string object with line-breaks, you can simply delete them:

```
import re
text = re.sub('\s*\n\s*', '', text)
```

To leave the line breaks in that follow the `</attack_headline>` delimiter, try:

```
re.sub('(?<!<\/attack_headline>)\s*\n\s*', '',  x)
```

Comment: will0EM... that sort of worked. It took all the text and made it ALL one line however I need to do this per event. In my example above. There are 3 events listed. Look closely. Each event ends at "</attack_headlines>"

Comment: I see, so is the desired output a block of text with one line per event?  Or a list object with one element per event?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
oneline = "".join(multiline.split())
```

Edit 1 (I've just seen your edit) - I will change your code like this:

```
with open(filename, "r") as fo:
    result = []
    for line in fo.readlines():
        result.append(line.strip())
    return result
```

Edit 2 (I've read your comment on the other answer) - You could do like this:

```
with open(filename, "r") as fo:
    partial = []
    for line in fo.readlines():
        if line.startswith("<"):
            yield "".join(partial)
            partial = []
        else:
            clean = line.strip()
            if clean:
                partial.append(clean)
```

Comment: Removing all whitespace will also remove spaces between tag name and argument name as in `<bla foo="">`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
# remove all newline whitespace stuff as in answer given before:
text = re.sub(r'\s*\n\s*', '', text)
# break again at desired points:
text = re.sub(r'</attack_headlines>', '</attack_headlines>\n', text)
```